# SLIM login manager on Ubuntu: no screen found

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

I'd like to use SLIM as my login manager in Ubuntu 10.10.  GDM works fine, but when I switch to SLIM, bootup hangs, and I get the following in /var/log/slim.log

```
X.Org X Server 1.9.0
Release Date: 2010-08-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-28-server x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux lapself 2.6.35-28-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 14:39:03 UTC 2011 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic root=UUID=4fd2ae3c-17c3-4496-8065-b77f2cd03348 ro quiet splash
Build Date: 09 January 2011  12:14:27PM
xorg-server 2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.18.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Apr  2 21:17:02 2011
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.
(EE) intel(0): Failed to become DRM master.
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Bad file descriptor
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [9]
param: 4, val: 0
(EE) intel(0): failed to get resources: Bad file descriptor
(EE) intel(0): Kernel modesetting setup failed
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this issue effects any login manager other than GDM and KDM.  It has to do with how the login manager is started.  In the case of SLIM, this happens in /etc/init.d/slim.  As a temporary workaround, I can get SLIM to load by modifying the following line in /etc/init.d/slim:

```
start-stop-daemon --start $SSD_START_ARGS ||echo -n " already running"
```

And replacing it with:

```
if [ "$(pidof slim)" ]; then
  echo -n " already running"
else
  exec /usr/bin/slim
fi
```

[Here is the original bug report](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/LLXmLyd1jDtopQV8eYti).